# Get CartoDB query by distance to work

Tags: distance, carto, query

Has anyone tried this tutorial: [Query by distance](http://developers.cartodb.com/tutorials/query_by_distance.html) ?

This is a copy of the final code which they use for the map:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.ie.css" />
  <![endif]-->  
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>
    <style>
    html, body {width:100%; height:100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    #map { width: 100%; height:100%; background: black;}
    #menu { position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 10px; width: 400px; height:60px; background: transparent; z-index:10;}
    #menu a { 
      margin: 15px 10px 0 0;
      float: right;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      width: 30px;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      font: bold 15px "Helvetica",Arial;
      line-height: normal;
      color: #555;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid #777777;
      background: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #menu a.selected,
    #menu a:hover { 
      color: #000;
    }            
    </style>

    <script>
    var map;

    function init() {
      // initiate leaflet map
      map = new L.Map('map', { 
        center: [20,-20],
        zoom: 3
      });

      L.tileLayer('https://dnv9my2eseobd.cloudfront.net/v3/cartodb.map-4xtxp73f/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'MapBox'
      }).addTo(map);

      var layerUrl = 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/9af23dd8-ea10-11e2-b5ac-5404a6a683d5/viz.json';

      var sublayers = [];

      cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl)
        .addTo(map)
        .on('done', function(layer) {
          // change the query for the first layer
          var subLayerOptions = {
            sql: "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_p_2 LIMIT 2000",
            cartocss: "#ne_10m_populated_p_2{marker-fill: #F84F40; marker-width: 8; marker-line-color: white; marker-line-width: 2; marker-clip: false; marker-allow-overlap: true;}"
          }

          var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);

          sublayer.set(subLayerOptions);

          sublayers.push(sublayer);
          detectUserLocation();
        }).on('error', function() {
          //log the error
        });

      // credit: http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/
      function detectUserLocation() {
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;

          navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
            mapToPosition, 
            alertError,
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
          );
        } else {
          alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
        }

        function alertError(error) {
          var errors = { 
            1: 'Permission denied',
            2: 'Position unavailable',
            3: 'Request timeout'
          };

          alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
        }
      }

      function mapToPosition(position){
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        updateQuery();
        map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat,lon), 7);
        new L.CircleMarker([lat,lon],{radius: 4}).addTo(map);
      }

      var lon,
          lat,
          total = 10;

      function updateQuery() {
        sublayers[0].set({
          sql: "WITH cities AS (SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom, the_geom_webmercator, name FROM ne_10m_populated_p_2 ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("+lon+","+lat+"),4326) ASC LIMIT "+total+") SELECT null as cartodb_id, ST_MakeLine(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("+lon+","+lat+"),4326),3857),the_geom_webmercator) as the_geom_webmercator, null as name FROM cities UNION ALL SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator, name FROM cities",
          cartocss: "#ne_10m_populated_p_2{[mapnik-geometry-type = 1]{text-name: [name]; text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book'; text-size: 12; text-fill: #000; text-allow-overlap: false; text-halo-fill: #FFF; text-halo-radius: 2;} [mapnik-geometry-type = 2]{line-color: white; line-opacity: 0.5;} } "
        });
      }

      $('.button').click(function() {
        $('.button').removeClass('selected'); $(this).addClass('selected');
        total = $(this).attr('id');
        updateQuery();
      });
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div id='map'></div>
  <div id='menu'>
    <a href="#500" id="500" value=500 class="button 500">500</a> 
    <a href="#100" id="100" value=100 class="button 100">100</a> 
    <a href="#50" id="50" value=50 class="button 50">50</a> 
    <a href="#10" id="10" value=10 class="button 10 selected">10</a> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see all of the points, but nothing else works, when I make the following changes:

- I replace var layerUrl with my viz.json link.
- I replace the name of their table, with the name of my table in the sql inside var subLayerOptions
- I replace the name of their table, with the name of my table in the css inside var subLayerOptions
- I replace the name of their table, with the name of my table in the cartocss inside sublayers[0].set

Am I missing something?

Does anyone have an example of this that they have got to work, with their data? Could I see the code?

Answer (score 1):

For anybody following this question, I've managed to answer it myself. I had edited all of the code correctly, however, if you wish to do this yourself, you will need to change the privacy setting of your table in cartoDB! I changed it from private to anybody with a link.